# Unable to Install Kivy in Anaconda Prompt on Windows 10 python 3.6

Tags: python, anaconda, kivy

I'm trying to install Kivy through Anaconda Prompt and keep running into a message saying the Kivy file does not exist. I may be having trouble with properly inputting the directory to the folder containing the download. Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: you might need to run the Anaconda Prompt as Administrator.

Comment: I've run the prompt as an admin and still get an error message that the file does not exist.

Comment: Please try installing kivy using *python -m pip install kivy*